# How to find all possible ascending and descending order from a list?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of number:

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,...,20]
```

I would like to generate all possible ascending and descending order of 6 total from my list.

```
possible_ordered:
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
[3,4,5,6,7,8]
...  
[15,16,17,18,19,20]
[20,19,18,17,16,15]
[15,14,13,12,11,10]
[10,9,8,7,6,5]
[6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

This is what I tried so far.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  
for x in a:  
 b = a[a.index(x):a.index(x)+6]  
 if len(b) == 6:  
  print b
```

output:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I don't know how to get the descending order and I'm not really sure this is a good code.

Comment: Please [edit] your quesiton and include the code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I'm so6ry.
I have edited it.

Comment: I don't understand the second half of your expected output. Is `[19 ,18, 17. 16, 15, 14]` expected, too?

Comment: Please include code that you have tried.

Comment: @Lutz Horn, The second half is showing the possibility of descending order from my list(number).

Comment: `[15,16,17,18,19,20]` this is the end of the possibility of ascending order, the rest is the possibility of descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = list(range(1, 21))
b = list(range(20, 0, -1)) # the revers of a

print([a[start: start + 6] for start in range(len(a) - 5)] +
      [b[start: start + 6] for start in range(len(a) - 5)])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
 [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15],
 [19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14],
 [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13],
 [17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12],
 [16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11],
 [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10],
 [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9],
 [13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8],
 [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7],
 [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
 [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
 [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4],
 [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
 [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```